# How can I add a record to a table defined in a django model containing a content_object field using raw sql?

Tags: sql, django, content-type

I got a model defined like this:

```
class LogEntry(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    content_type =  models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, blank=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
usr = User.objects.all()[0]
new_record = LogEntry.objects.create(text="foobar", content_object=usr)
```

But how do I create the same record using plain SQL? The problem is of course how to determine how to insert values into the fields content_type and content_object.

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
     insert into appname_log_entry SET (text, content_type, object_id) 
     calues(%s, %s, %s)""", \ 
     ['foobar', <how to get content type?>, ModelInstance.Id])
```

Do I have to set the content_objcet? If so how?

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you want to do this.

In any case, the `content_type` field is just a standard foreign key. So you can get is ID the same way you get any other FK id, via `model_instance.content_type_id`.

Comment: I'm creating a package for delayed/caching logging package for django, which cannot use the orm to insert records and have to use raw sql. Tried to figure something out using User.content_type_id,but that attribute does not exist.

Comment: No, because `User` doesn't have a generic relation. But `LogEntry`, as you've shown it above, does.